# Find a diagonal matrix D such that the gershgorin disks of the matrix $B=D^{-1}AD$ do not include the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am given that

$$ A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 4 \\
        -5 & 9 
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Find a diagonal matrix D such that the gerschgorin disks of the matrix $B=D^{-1}AD$ do not include the origin?

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: You can't solve the matrix equation for $D$, if that's what you're asking.  In most cases, a solution won't exist, and when a solution exists, multiple solutions will do.

Comment: Why dont you start by letting $D=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 \\
0 & b
 \end{array}
\right)$ and see what you can get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take 
$$
D = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&a}
$$
and we would find that
$$
DAD^{-1} = 
\pmatrix
{3 & 4/a\\
5a & 9}
$$
So, all we need to do now is find an $a>0$ so that $4/a \leq 3$ and $5a \leq 9$.